# How do I replace this bathtub handle that has a plastic piece?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, replacement

I have followed a number of videos, but they all seem to have a copper (?) stem. At this point I'm up to some plastic piece that has no notches (namely around the metal piece) to use a wrench on.

Where do I go from here? I'm thinking that I would pull it out, but don't want to risk it without being sure.

It is leaking, so I'm probably looking to replace more than just the knob.

[image]

[EDIT] I went to Lowe's and they cannot help me without knowing the brand. What would be a way to determine the brand? I do not see any labels, here are more pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIdhZ.jpg

Comment: There may be yet another screw deep inside the hollow shaft of the plastic piece. If there is a screw in there, take it out and the plastic piece should pull straight out.

Comment: There's almost certainly a screw down the shaft like Shirlock said.

Comment: Do you want to replace the valve or just the handle? Does the other knob fit? if so, take it to a plumbing supply store.  They will try it on new valve replacement stems (some have boards of stems already made up) and sell you a new handle

Comment: The valve manufacturer may be on the back of the brass valve body.  Do you have an access panel behind the tub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not worried about possibly damaging the plastic bit (after all you are looking to remove it), I would get a pair of [vice grips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79HFw.jpg) onto the square section at the back of the plastic piece.

This will allow you to either rotate the plug (to un-screw it, if it's threaded or to break the bond if it's glued in), or apply horizontal force to pull it out without damaging it too much.